# JSON error when save color in RGB format

Tags: jquery, json, rgb

I have searched around and could not find the answer, or maybe it's just something buggy in my json code?

```
JSON file:
{
  "html": {
    "content": "<div style=\"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); height: 11px; width: 111px;\"></div>"
  }
}

background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); --> NO
background-color: #000000; --> OK
```

PHP:

```
$jsonPathSite = '/site/01.json';
$jsonFileSite = file_get_contents($jsonPathSite);
$jsonReadSite = jsonDecode($jsonFileSite,true);

// Saving the file
$jsonReadSite['html']['content'] = $content;

file_put_contents( $jsonPathSite, json_encode($jsonReadSite) );
```

Its not able to be saved as RGB format?

but if i used HEX format the json file completely fine!

Comment: It doesn't look like a json file

Comment: @JimiDini sorry! its just a brief code from json file!

Comment: Still don't get it. You somehow create JSON from this html string? Show exact JSON example.

Comment: What are you doing with the generated JSON?

Comment: and what's the error you have? because it seems to work for me (at least the decoding part)

Comment: Works for me also, checked in console. How do you check this is not works?

Comment: So now the question is: what kind of error are you trying to achieve? :)

Comment: sorry guys. just found out. there was something wrong with my json decoding.. so it fixed now :_)